# Installing Ubuntu 14.04/14.10 on a UEFI laptop with Nvidia GeForce 840M

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, uefi, bumblebee, nvidia-prime

**My laptop:**
i7 with built-in Intel HD 4400, 8GB ram, Nvidia GeForce 840**M**, Broadcom WiFi, Windows 8.1 64 bit.

I have tried to get Linux to work but ran into a lot of issues such as screen tearing and flickering. Using bumblebee would make the screen blank, system would not shut down properly and battery would be empty upon boot up, so I got fed up & just gave up (I am new to the Linux world).

Summary of the steps I followed originally:

- Turn off fast start-up
- Turn off UEFI mode
- Turn off secure boot
- Use Rufus to create a bootable USB
- Install Ubuntu in ~20GB of space.

I want to try again now, but am unsure if I should do what I did before or if I can improve the steps or do something differently or is it easier in 15.04.

Comment: screen tearing / flickering might related to your graphic card, let's put bumblebee aside, have you tried to install the nvidia proprietary driver for it?

Comment: @P.-H.Lin  I selected the propreitary drivers in the additional drivers tab, it had the same effect :(

Comment: Try the latest nvidia driver here : http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Answer (score 1):

NVIDIA works perfectly in 15.04, I no longer get any shut down issues, and I can easily switch between Intel and Nvidia.

I didn't download any drivers, I simply installed 15.04, went to **Additional Drivers** and selected the proprietary Nvidia 346.59 driver and rebooted, everything went smoothly on the graphics card side although there is the occasional tearing when using Nvidia though it's probably Nvidia's fault.